# Spring-boot - How to load resources/datasources?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I've been using Spring Boot and deploying the application via a `.jar` file. I want to load **multiple datasources**. When I was using local tomcat I used to add them to `context.xml`, but now I'm using the embedded tomcat and was wondering if it's possible to load them via some external file or some way which I would put on the server (UAT/PROD).

I've found a sample of how to do it via Java Class, but I was wondering if it's possible to do it other way as I'd like to leave the user/password out of the `.jar` and the configurations on a local file on the server. (looks easier/faster for future developments). Maybe using a "`datasource.yml`" or something similar..

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks!

My `context.xml` :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

    <!-- ABC QA -->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/abc"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="5"
        maxIdle="2"
        username="xxx"
        maxWait="1000"
        validationQuery="select 1"         
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        password="xxx"     
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://server-qa.com:1234;databaseName=myDB"/>

    <!-- DEF QA -->
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/def"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="5"
        maxIdle="2"
        username="xxx"
        maxWait="1000"
        validationQuery="select 1"         
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        password="xxx"     
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://server2-qa.com:1234;databaseName=myDB"/>

</Context>
```

Ps.: In case anyone wants to check the java I refer to, the link is: https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/jndi/SampleTomcatJndiApplication.java

## Update:

after a bit of changes this code below now works in case anyone needs it! :)

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 9998

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG

spring.ds_db1:
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://mydb1.com:1433;databaseName=mydb1
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.ds_db2:
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://mydb2.com:1433;databaseName=mydb2
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

`DatabaseConfig`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_db1")
public class DatabaseDb1Config {

    @Bean(name="dsDb1")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ds_db1.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ds_db1.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ds_db1.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ds_db1.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="jdbcDb1")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsChange) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsChange);
    }

}
```

`Repository`

```
@Service
public class ContractRepositoryImpl implements ContractRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcDb1")
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public Contract getContract(long id) {
        return jdbc.queryForObject("SELECT ...", contractMapper, id);
    }

    private static final RowMapper<Contract> contractMapper = new RowMapper<Contract>() {
        public Contract mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Contract contract = new Contract(rs.getLong("contract"), rs.getString("name"));
            return contract;
        }
    };

}
```

Relevant part from `pom.xml`

```
...
<spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQL SERVER DRIVER FOR LEGACY CONNECTIONS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: since is a jar with tomcat embeded, I dont really think is possible to leave the resource outside, even if you have your xml file, when deploy the jar, will create all over again, its not like with the war file, maybe you should consider using war files

Comment: hi @jpganz18, I will give one last try, but indeed.. maybe I should just go with .war and be happy ! :)

Comment: to leave them outside the app you can easily set them using zookeeper, take a look of it, I use it often for this issues but you will have to go into more configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the datasources with application.properties (or .yml) files. See the list of [available properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database).

Spring Boot will read [configuration files from different sources](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config), one would be the directory in which the JAR file is stored, or you provide the values with System Properties or environment variables.

Comment: hi dunni! not sure what I'm doing wrong... I was reading lots of articles but nothing seems to work yet.. I updated the question with the code to reflect what I'm trying.. can you help me to figure out ?

Comment: I changed a bit the code and now it's working.. Thanks for pointing out it reads from the same folder of the `.jar` !